# All-caps in Moderator Timeline

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools

The new post timeline for moderators (as opposed as to the old obscure question timeline for everyone) is very helpful, but it seems that it sometimes gets a *tad* over-excited when a mod converts an answer to a comment. Can we get it to be in line with all the other status events in all-lowercase?

[image: screenshot of mod timeline for a post with "mod converts to comment" in all-caps]

Comment: Counterproposal: ALL MOD ONLY INFO SHOULD BE IN ALL CAPS. I REALIZE THAT WOULD BE SHOUTING, BUT IT'S THE ONLY WAY THE INFO CAN BE HEARD OVER THE HAMMER HITTING SOUNDS.

Comment: I can't reproduce this here.

Comment: @Oded: I see it in the timeline of the deleted _answer_ to this question.  The question timeline is not at issue.

Comment: @JonEricson - Ah. The _answer_ timeline. Makes sense. I have identified the responsible piece of code and pinged the developer, as it _may_ be intentional.

Comment: It was intentional, to get my attention when I needed to localize one of the values (not all the history types are displayed and I'm lazy).

Comment: @JarrodDixon Yay, "localization"! So there's still hope for the non-English sites pending private beta on Area 51?